# Как вывести информацию о повторяющихся данных 2D массива (DataFrame)?

Tags: python, массивы, pandas

К примеру есть массив:

```
1 1 1 0 2
0 1 1 2 1
0 0 2 1 1
```

На вывод

```
0 - 4
1 - 8
2 - 3
```

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Шаг 1. Load data file
data_file = pd.read_excel('Arrayt.xlsx')

# Шага 2. Выводит список элементов с частотами
data_file.stack().value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'val', 0:'count'})'


# Сейчас просматриваю уроки по сохранению и выводу полученных данных на Шаге 2.
```

**В самом начале задача была формализована так:**

Задан массив

```
A11 
A12 
A13
A14
A15
A16
...
A1n
```

Нужно вывести

```
A12-A11     None
A13-A11   A13-A12    None
A14-A11   A14-A12   A14-A13
A15-A11   A15-A12   A15-A13
A16-A11   A16-A12   A16-A13
...       ...       ... 
A1n-A11   A1n-A12   A1n-A12
```

Эту часть я выполнил топорным способом в эксель. Уже импортирован массив в Python (спасибо форумачанину MaxU). Опять же благодаря подсказке MaxU произведен вывод каждого элемента матрицы с частотами.

*Задача стоит всю реализацию перенести в Python*

Comment: Хочу это проделать с массивом 100 на 100 Для этого я импортирую пакет пандас 
import pandas as pd 
mydata =pd.io.excel.read_excel(open("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Arr‌​aytest.xlsx")) 
print mydata 
Но достаточно ли для импорта пандас вышенаписанного? Питон ругается на "BadZipfile " – UnoMan 12 минут назад

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться - для чего вы скопировали мой ответ в свой вопрос? И в чем теперь состоит вопрос? ;-)

Comment: На StackOverflow (SO) принято задавать один вопрос и не менять его суть, т.к. это делает недействительными уже данные вам ответы. Если хотите задать еще один вопрос  - задайте (откройте) новый вопрос.

Comment: MaxU Спасибо за помощь! И уточнение о работе со StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно [прочитать данные из Excel в Pandas.DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Ar‌​r‌​aytest.xlsx')
```

Ответ на вопрос о повторяющихся данных:

```
In [131]: df
Out[131]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  0  2
1  0  1  1  2  1
2  0  0  2  1  1
```

В виде Pandas.Series:

```
In [132]: df.stack().value_counts()
Out[132]:
1    8
0    4
2    3
dtype: int64

In [143]: df.stack().value_counts(sort=False)
Out[143]:
0    4
1    8
2    3
dtype: int64
```

В виде Pandas.DataFrame:

```
In [134]: df.stack().value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'val', 0:'count'})
Out[134]:
   val  count
0    1      8
1    0      4
2    2      3

In [144]: df.stack().value_counts(sort=False) \
            .reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'val', 0:'count'})
Out[144]:
   val  count
0    0      4
1    1      8
2    2      3
```

Пояснения:

```
In [135]: df.stack()
Out[135]:
0  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
   3    0
   4    2
1  0    0
   1    1
   2    1
   3    2
   4    1
2  0    0
   1    0
   2    2
   3    1
   4    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция set(a) создаёт множество без повторяющихся элементов, по которому и проходим в цикле.

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1]
for i in set(a):
    print(str(i) + ' - ' + str(a.count(i)))
```

Comment: Очень неэффективно

Comment: Хочу это проделать с массивом 100 на 100

Для этого я импортирую пакет пандас

import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.io.excel.read_excel(open("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Arraytest.xlsx"))

print mydata

Но достаточно ли для импорта пандас вышенаписанного? Питон ругается на "BadZipfile "